# How to bind a keybinding to add `\textit` or `textbf` for the word, where the cursor is pointing?

Tags: key-bindings, latex

I am working on a `LaTex` file.

Is it possible to bind a keybinding to add `\textit` or `textbf` for the word, where the cursor is pointing?

For example, cursor is on top of word `hello`:

- `hello` converted into `\textit{hello}` # with `M-o i`
- `hello` converted into `\textbf{hello}`  # with `M-o b`

Comment: How about using the `yasnippet` library and writing your own snippet, or just copying an existing snippet that does something exactly the same or very similar thereto?  I personally use a custom snippet that surrounds an active region with similar/same codes, or if there is no active region, then it leaves the cursor in between the wavy brackets to insert the text manually and then the tab key exits and places the cursor after the closing wavy bracket.

Comment: I think `M-o i` is the default keybinding but not achieve any change on my end. I will look into `yasnippet ` library

Comment: Auctex already has this with the `C-c C-f`, which is the `TeX-font` command. it works like a prefix, thus you type something more to choose what you want. For bold you use `C-c C-f C-b`. It is also "smart" and if you use inside an equation it will use `\mathbf` instead. Type `C-c C-f C-h` to see all possibilities. You might set a different keybinding for `TeX-font` for easier typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create commands to achieve the job you want and link them to the key you like.

```
(defun italic-word ()
 "your comment" 
 (interactive) 
 (easy-mark) (TeX-font nil 9))

(defun bold-word ()
 "your comment" 
 (interactive) 
 (easy-mark) (TeX-font nil 2))
 
 (bind-key (kbd "M-o i") #'italic-word LaTeX-mode-map)
 (bind-key  (kbd "M-o b") #'bold-word LaTeX-mode-map)
```

"M-o i" and "M-o b" are already bind. It is not a good idea to use them.

the function easy-mark come with the easy-kill package on elpa. Probably you need to install it.

*edit :*
I don't really like this code that operates on the mark. I think easy-mark should be for interactive use only. So I suggest you replace with this more robust code:

```
(defun italic-word ()
 "your comment" 
 (interactive) 
 (save-excursion
   (beginning-of-thing 'word)
   (insert "\\textit{")
   (end-of-thing 'word)
   (insert "}")))

(defun bold-word ()
 "your comment" 
 (interactive)
 (save-excursion
   (beginning-of-thing 'word)
   (insert "\\textbf{")
   (end-of-thing 'word)
   (insert "}")))
```

Comment: Can I bind something like `M-u i` ? Not sure what is `M-o i` bind to

Comment: M-u is bind to 'upcase-word. You can reveal what a key is bind to with C-h k

Comment: It does `{\bf doo}` instead can I do `\textbf{hello}` ?

Comment: `(global-set-key (kbd "M-o i" #'italic-word)` does not work on my end :-(

Comment: It's an horrible typo. I missed the closing parenthesis. I corrected it and change the global bindings for latex-mode only bindings.

Comment: latex-mode-map is set from latex-mode. this message should not appear if you are in latex mode. You said the question was about editing latex code

Comment: now it prints `{\it hello\/}` I want as `\textit{hello}`if its possible

Comment: I suspect you are in tex-mode. You should be in latex-mode. Check the display on the modeline

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, it works under `LaTeX/P` mode, but keybinding gives an error whenever I try to open a .py file or different file format; it can be a global keybinding anyway

Comment: something like this: `(global-set-key (kbd "M-o i") 'italic-word)` or maybe it can defined under latex-hook